# scanf() doesn't prompt input in stdin

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float base, height, hyp;

    printf("input base of triangle:\n");
    scanf("%f", base);

    printf("input height of triangle:\n");
    scanf("%f", height);

    printf("input hypotenuse of triangle:\n");
    scanf("%f", hyp);

    float perimeter = base + height + hyp;

    printf("the perimeter of your triangle is: %f\n", perimeter);



    return 0;
}
```

I'm running this through ideone.com and it shows success, then standard input is empty, then in stdout it prints all my print statements with no numbers

Comment: `scanf("%f", base);` --> `scanf("%f", &base);`

Comment: ideone will never wait for your input, type all your input into stdin box

Comment: Type something in the input **before** running the program and you'll get something like `Runtime error time: 0 memory: 2172 signal:11` because you call `scanf` incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

This is because ideone is *not* interactive. Unlike running your program from the command line, ideone requires you to provide all the input upfront in the "input" tab:

[image: Ideone]

You need to enter all your data *before* running your program.

P.S. Once you do, notice how you have undefined behavior because you pass values, rather than pointers, to `scanf`. The best way to address this on ideone is to pick "C99 strict" option when compiling your C code. This would break your compile with the following warning:

> prog.c:7:11: error: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Werror=format=]
>
> ```
>  scanf("%f", base);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` requires a pointer to your data type, you should pass the address of your variables using `&`:

```
scanf("%f", &base);
scanf("%f", &height);
scanf("%f", &hyp);
```

To add, some error checking might be useful, something like:

```
if(scanf("%f", &base) != 1) //number of items scanned is expected to be 1
  //process error..
//etc
```

Comment: ... and add code to check that the scanning succeeded, before relying on the variable having a proper value.

Comment: @4386427 `scanf` returns negative on failure.

Comment: @GillBates: And otherwise it returns the number of items scanned. If the input is not a floating-point number, it returns 0. Check for success by verifying that the result is exactly the number of items expected.

Comment: @GillBates `scanf` return `EOF` on I/O failure or end-of-file.    Failure to convert input does not return `EOF` per the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426858/scanf-doesnt-prompt-input-in-stdin#comment68102457_40426890), but 0 in this case.